# Docker compose of Playwright/Typescript project Paths handling error

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, node-modules, playwright

I have a Playwright/Typescript project with couple of test.ts files. I would like to run it on Docker, that's why I created a yaml file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "1440:1433"
```

Created a Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.30.0-focal

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json /app/
COPY Extensions /app/Extensions

COPY . .

RUN rm -rf node_modules && npm install

CMD ["npx","cross-env","ENV=qa","npm","run","test"]
```

in package.json have a "scripts": {
"test": "npx playwright test"

but due to environment handling have to run the tests with npx cross-env ENV=qa npm run test

My tsconfig.json file contains specific paths,

```
"paths": {
        "@pages/*":["pageActions/*"],
        "@objects/*":["pageObjects/*"],
        "@extensions/*":["extensions/*"],
        "@navigations/*":["navigations/*"]
      }
```

which are not proper somehow and after `docker compose up --build` command got an error:

Error: Cannot find module '@extensions/APIActions'
Require stack:

- /app/tests/GETtest.test.ts
- /app/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/transform.js
- /app/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/configLoader.js
- /app/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/runner.js
- /app/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/cli.js
- /app/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/cli/cli.js
- /app/node_modules/playwright-core/cli.js
- /app/node_modules/@playwright/test/cli.js

  at GETtest.test.ts:1

> 1 | import { APIActions } from '@extensions/APIActions';
> Can you help me how to solve it?

i have tried several run and copy options. Found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths but I don't know how to use it, or is it what I need